# ELB health check for redirect endpoint

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-elb

I have a web application running on Apache2 (2.4)
and i am redirecting the homepage and entire website (/*) to another url, kind of auth and then returns back to the homepage

So in my apache2 location directive

```
...
<Location "/">
        AuthType AuthAgent
        Require valid-user
        Satisfy any
</Location>
...
```

So know ELB is failing health check because the homepage is being used as endpoint for health check.

How do i do it so that ELB passes healthcehck when the redirection happens. Redirection is 302

I just want ELB to say pass on 302 or however i can make the healthcheck pass

Thanks

Comment: In the health check settings in the ELB, just add 302 as a valid response code...

Comment: Are you using Classic ELB or an Application Load Balancer?

Comment: @MattHouser am using classic ELB

Comment: @MarkB i don't see where to edit settings to add 302 as valid response..i am using classic ELB

Answer (score 0):

Classic ELB will only consider a 200 response as a success. Everything else is a health check failure (including a 302).

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-healthchecks.html (see under "Ping Path")

You have 2 options:

Option 1: Switch to use an Application Load Balancer instead. By doing this, you can configure it to accept 302 as a health check success.

Option 2: Add a non-redirect URL to your web server specifically for the health check. So you would have something like `/healthcheck.html` return a 200 success and everything else return a redirect 302.

Comment: How can i do the Option 2 if i want to keep my current setting? I need to redirect homepage to that auth url and then back

Any way i can achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i did to solve the issue PERFECTLY!

i added regex to the location directive so that it redirects all except some URL i dont want to redirect

```
...
<Location ~ "^((?!/status).)*$">
        AuthType AuthAgent
        Require valid-user
        Satisfy any
</Location>
...
```

so it redirects everything except `/status/`